Why is the Windows routing registry value IPEnableRouter = 1 no longer working?
In Windows 11 23H2 (Build 22631.4037) the IPEnableRouter registry value is no longer working.
If you set the following registry value to enable routing in Windows, the value disappears after a reboot and routing is not enabled.
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters!IPEnableRouter = 1
It is still working machines with Windows 11 22H2, not sure after which update it stopped working.
Why is the IPEnableRouter registry value no longer working in the latest version of Windows?

the same issue is on our end here. We did some digging and we found that the Host Network Service was/is removing it from the registry. As a test, I turned off the service and manually entered the key and, surprise-surprise the key stayed after reboot.
I'm not too fond of the fix, but it works for now.
I didn't see any mention of IPEnableRouter in the last Windows release notes, but I also didn't read too much into it.

Interesting. A colleague wrote me, that the following power shell command should enable the routing in Windows instead of the Registry key (did not test it yet): "Set-NetIPInterface -Forwarding Enabled"
Since it is not mentioned somewhere, I guess it is a bug.

We also have this issue for one of our clients.  Initially we removed offending update KB5041585 - but have now disabled Host Network Service and restored reg key as a temp work around.
Imagine not many setups require routing in Windows 11.

I have a similar problem with Windows 11 24H2 machine running OpenVPN server.
Before (23H2) all was working fine. With 24H2 the forwarding doesn't work anymore, both with the "Set-NetIPInterface -Forwarding Enabled" or with the registry key IPEnableRouter and Host Network Service disabled.
Rolling back to 23H2 the forwarding works as expected, even without the IPEnableRouter key but with the forwarding enabled with the PowerShell command.
